# RTSP Streaming on ios 4.0?

Tags: ios4, rtsp

I am working on an application that runs the live video taken from the server and play it on iphone os4.0 . When I run the application on iOS 4.0,, after few seconds it gets paused, even if i play it it wont work any more.

I tried a lot but it doesn't worked. But it is clearly stated in iOS 4.0 documentation that iOS 4.0 supports rtsp streaming. Can anybody has any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Also, HTTP Live Streaming is supported in Safari and the media player framework on iOS. RTSP streaming is not supported."

That's from the FAQ in the HTTP Live Streaming Overview in the iOS 4.1 docs. RTSP is explicitly **not supported**. I've seen it done on iOS - in VLC, for example - but no, it's definitely not supported natively.

Comment: Thank you Morgan. I did worked on it and got the same answer. Their are few private libraries that support RTSP on iOS but those are not supported by Apple. Anyways Thanks For your support.

Comment: @Madhu read the answer. RTSP is not supported. It never will be.